# Replacing a DDR2 memory with another that is faster

Tags: ddr2

Are there any known timing issues with directly replacing on board one DDR2 SDRAM with another package and pin compatible DDR2 that is slightly faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean replacing an IC on a board, not replacing a memory module.

If that is the case, and provided the parts meet the [DDR2 standard](https://www.jedec.org/standards-documents/docs/jesd-79-2e) (every part I have ever seen does) then there should be little difficulty provided you intend to run the part *at the speed of the part you are replacing*. That said, One particular check to make is that the inputs and outputs properly meet the SSTL_1.8 requirements.

Most timing parameter issues are with the controller rather than the memory devices.

It will be prudent to re-check the timing parameters, but I have done this (due to parts becoming obsolete as slower parts simply do not sell) on numerous occasions with no problems at all.

There is no reason at all that a part rated for 800/1600 operation cannot be run at 400/800 speeds; just make sure the correct CAS value (in particular) is loaded at DDR initialisation. I have never had to change a DDR memory side parameter when replacing old parts with higher speed capability devices.